# Using "symmetry" within Coq expressions

Tags: coq

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following in Coq. Say we have proved the following:

trans_lemma: a = b -> b = c -> a = c

and we want to use it to deduce that

b = a -> c = b -> a = c.

I can't seem to be able to get "apply trans_lemma with ..." to work whatever I do. It would seem like I would need to rewrite equations in trans_lemma, so that the variables would match in the same order. Is there some trivial way of doing this without reproving the lemma, i.e. can I somehow apply the "symmetry" tactic on an equation within an expression?

(I know I can prove what I want without using the lemma by just using a few intros and rewrites, but I would like to know if there's a syntactic way of reusing the result that I already have.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot apply something to your lemma that will change its shape magically. What you can do here is to introduce your equalities `b = a` and `c =b`, then apply your lemma, leaving you with two goals that can easily be proven by symmetry of `=`.

In general, I don't think you can apply tactics to terms in the way you wished you could.

---

Now a few additional things:

- if the `=` here is Coq's equality, you actually don't need a lemma, as transitivity is given to you by the system.
- your lemma should be polymorphic : `trans_lemma : forall {T} (a b c : T), a = b -> b = c -> c = d`. Maybe you show us this one because you are in a section, but then you should probably deduce that second goal once you've closed the section.

(you might also be interested in reusing the `Transitive` type class from `Coq.Classes.RelationClasses`...)